# Creating table without skipping a row

Tags: psql

I'm using a sql and trying to create a table using the following:

```
CREATE TABLE NameTable (  
 id integer is not null,
 classA TEXT,
 classB TEXT,
 classC TEXT,
 classD TEXT,
 classE TEXT,
 classF TEXT,
 classG VARCHAR(2)
);  

 \COPY NameTable FROM 'C:/.../file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

When I use the 'select from nametable;'

My result is

```
  id | classA | classB | class C | ....
----------+------------------+---------
   2 |   a |   p |   ...   
   3 |   p |   n |   ...  
   ...
```

As you can see after I create my table id 1 is missing from output. why did this happen and how I can fix it ?  Also those  a= average, p= positive, n=negative

Comment: On the other hand, why do you care?

Comment: You list two databases, are you asking for both? Does HEADER take in to account your header is two lines?

Comment: only problem I'm having is id column missing one row. The id go from 1 - 20 but somehow is end up going from 1-19  instead missing one row.

Comment: they are not two database rather they only one database in this query @DaveNewton

Comment: mysql is a database management system. psql is also a database management system These are two database management systems

Comment: indeed @Strawberry

Comment: I know nothing at all about psql, but surely the 'header' keyword implies that there is a header row that you wish to ignore

Comment: Yep, when I look back at my csv file my row and column doesnt have a header. Now i see thank @Strawberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your csv file doesn't contain a header as the first row then try to remove `HEADER` from your command. Also if you are missing the last row of the CSV file it could be that you need to put a line break after the final line in the csv

Comment: Thank so much @SimonD

Comment: The header,  "\COPY NameTable FROM 'C:/.../file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV" I just removed and already have the complete table